# Convert between URL and windows filename (Java)?

Tags: java, windows, file, url

Is there a standard/good way of converting between urls and windows filenames, in Java?

I am trying to download files, but I want the windows filename to be convertible back to the original filename.  Note that the query portion of the url is vital, as I will be downloading different pages that differ only in query.

My current hacky solution is to replace illegal characters (such as '?') with a specific string (such as 'QQ'), but this makes conversion back to url less transparent.  Is there a better way?

Comment: Some examples of what you're trying to accomplish would be very helpful.

Comment: I think he's talking about saving off the results of a web request by using the web URL as the filename.  This runs into problems with characters such as '*' and '?', which are valid in a URL but invalid as part of a Windows file name.

Comment: i.e. www.google.com/search?q=bad+urls, which would not be a valid windows filename (due to the question mark).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could do worse than use [URLEncoder](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) to encode the URL:

```
String url = "http://172.0.0.1:80/foo/bar/baz.txt?black=white";
String filename = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
File file = new File(filename);
```

The filename becomes the legal win32 name:

```
http%3A%2F%2F172.0.0.1%3A80%2Ffoo%2Fbar%2Fbaz.txt%3Fblack%3Dwhite
```

This is a reversible operation:

```
String original = URLDecoder.decode(filename, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 2):

The java.io.File class takes a URI &| filename as a constructor, but contains `toURI()` & `toURL()` methods as well as `getName()` & `getPath()`.  I assume this would be a valid conversion for you?

Answer (score 2):

But is it possible to encode url to filename at all? I mean, can there be the 100% valid solution? I think that converting url to filename is the wrong idea in general, because of different limitations set on urls and filenames:

[Max filename length (NTFS filesystem, Unicode, using UTF-16 encoding) - 255](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Comparison_of_filename_limitations)

[Max URL length (using UTF-8 encoding?) - 2000 chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to convert an URL encoded to non encoder you could use:

[URLDecoder](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html)

> *Utility class for HTML form decoding. This class contains static methods for decoding a String from the application/x-www-form-urlencoded  MIME format.*

See if that's what you need.

Comment: @Paul: Add some samples of the input and desired ouput to better understand your question