# how to use XML sent by html form?

Tags: java, xml, network-programming

i have html form with textarea in which i paste some XML, for example:

```
<network ip_addr="10.0.0.0/8" save_ip="true">
<subnet interf_used="200" name="lan1" />
<subnet interf_used="254" name="lan2" />
</network>
```

When user submit form, that data is send to Java server, so in headers i get something like that:

```
GET /?we=%3Cnetwork+ip_addr%3D%2210.0.0.0%2F8%22+save_ip%3D%22true%22%3E%0D%0A%3Csubnet+interf_used%3D%22200%22+name%3D%22lan1%22+%2F%3E%0D%0A%3Csubnet+interf_used%3D%22254%22+name%3D%22lan2%22+%2F%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fnetwork%3E HTTP/1.1
```

how can i use that in my Java applications? I need to make some calculations on that data and re-send new generated XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652483/convert-between-url-and-windows-filename-java/1652560#1652560) shows how to use the URLDecoder/URLEncoder classes to decode and encode url strings. It should work if you passed the 'GET' string to the URLDecoders decode method.

---

**To answer your following question (comment)**

First you need to extract this xml based response from the url string. Maybe it's enough to create a substring starting with the first `<` char.

The String should be fed into a XML parser to create a DOM document. The last easy task would be walking through that document and copying the values to your internal network model.

[Do not think about using RegExp to extract the data.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) Use a parser.

Comment: Thanks, great. Now i have string like: /?we=<network ip_addr="10.0.0.0/8" save_ip="true"><subnet interf_used="200" name="lan1" /><subnet interf_used="254" name="lan2" /></network>

How can i put it to for example an array?